how do I get the a count of ports open and being used in ubuntu?
I want to get the number of ports available in Ubuntu, unused ports that are not being used by a program, below is what I tried
sudo netstat -tln | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d: -f2 | sort -n | uniq | wc -l

but this seems to return a number too small, so I believe this is wrong, also I want to get the number of ports being used in Ubuntu, below is my code and it seems to work
netstat -nat | awk '{print $4}' | grep -E ":[0-9]+" | cut -d: -f2 | sort | uniq | wc -l

but I can't verify this is correct

You seem to start from the misconception that a port is some delimited entity which can be in use or free. In reality, what is commonly referred to as port is actually just a number between 0 and 65535 which together with an IP address defines one side of a TCP connection or UDP association.
Specifically, one and the same port number can appear many times in the output of netstat. Different processes can listen on the same port number for different IP addresses, and at the same time the same port number can appear on one or the other side of different established TCP connections. None of these "occupies" the port number in a way that would exclude other uses.
In conclusion, counting how many distinct port numbers appear in the output of netstat commands with various options just doesn't produce anything meaningful.
